# SwiftUI: Sign-in with Apple button crashes the app when shown inside NavigationLink or Sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

We are developing a SwiftUI watchOS application and we want to support sign-in with Apple functionality. Because there is no SwiftUI component for it, we are using WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable to show. Initially, this was shown as a first view with other sign-in options and we had no issue but then we decided to add these to some navigation flows and it started to crash.

Just to clarify, the below code works:

```
struct QWSplashScreenView: View {
    @State var showLogin: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        QWSignInView(showEmailLogin: self.$showLogin)
    }
}
```

While this one, does not:

```
struct QWSplashScreenView: View {
    @State var showLogin: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: QWSignInView(showEmailLogin: self.$showLogin), label: { Text("Login") })
    }
}
```

Crash is completely at system level, just to show initial part of it:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x010d33d2 static PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptor.platformView(for:) + 50
1   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x010d3c8c protocol witness for static PlatformViewRepresentable.platformView(for:) in conformance PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptor<A> + 28
2   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x011d7d5b PlatformViewHost.representedView.getter + 27
3   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x011e68f4 PlatformViewHost.init(_:host:environment:viewPhase:) + 340
4   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x011e2a8e PlatformViewHost.__allocating_init(_:host:environment:viewPhase:) + 46
5   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x011e235e closure #1 in PlatformViewChild.update(context:) + 1662
6   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x011ddaa9 PlatformViewChild.update(context:) + 553
7   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x011e4057 protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update(_:graph:attribute:) in conformance PlatformViewChild<A> + 39
8   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x035c0791 partial apply + 33
9   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x035a8d99 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 461
```

Does anyone have seen this behaviour? (Same crash happens if I use sheet as well)

The code of QWSignInView:

```
struct QWSignInView: View {
    @Binding var showEmailLogin: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Record and save your blood pressure measurements")

            VStack() {
                QWSignInWithAppleButton()
                    .frame(height:40)

                Button(action: {
                    self.showEmailLogin = true
                }) {

                    Text("I have an account")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the QWSignInWithAppleButton:

```
final class QWSignInWithAppleButton: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {
    typealias WKInterfaceObjectType = WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton

    func makeWKInterfaceObject(context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<QWSignInWithAppleButton>) -> WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
        WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.buttonPressed))
    }

    func updateWKInterfaceObject(_ wkInterfaceObject: WKInterfaceAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<QWSignInWithAppleButton>) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator {
        @objc func buttonPressed() {
            appStore.loginStore.beginAppleIDSignIn()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `NavigationView` somewhere in parent of `QWSplashScreenView` with `NavigationLink`?

Comment: No, I do not. QWSplashScreenView is inside the main WKHostingController (Initial main view)

Comment: Agh... sorry, it is Watch app, there is no NavigationView there. Please, disregard above.

Comment: Does it crash right on QWSplashScreenView or when you tap NavigationLink?

Comment: When you tap it, from the debug I can see that makeCoordinator runs then makeWKInterfaceObject and when I return appleIdButton I get the crash.

Comment: Just tested with Xcode 11.4 - on Simulator works fine. Does it crash on device only?

Comment: Weird, I am testing with Simulator and on Xcode 11.4. Strangely, in the beginning this was not happening but once it started happen, now I get crash every time.